# What are some accepted terms for an object with exactly three properties?

Tags: data-structures, terminology, naming

Many of you are likely familiar with the term (and well defined struct in many languages) that is a key-value pair, or `kvp` for short.

I'm not asking for opinions or a scholarly debate here - the term key-value pair is derived from strongly typed languages where this is an actual type (i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-7.0).

I want to know if there are commonplace or accepted terms for a data struct that has three and only three properties - much like the KVP struct provides a contract that it will have a key and a value - with links to good sources (i.e. early C++ documentation, API docs, some IEEE standard somewhere) that shows this data struct and it's name in actual use.

Are there examples of these sorts of data structs in any strongly typed languages of today? Is it a Triad? A Thruple? A Troupe?

I've been searching the big bad web and come up short - at least in terms of finding authoritative sources.

Here's an example using TypeScript, generics, and my naive attempt at naming it:

```
type KeyValueTypeTriad<T> = {
  key: string;
  value: any;
  type: T;
};
```

Comment: You're looking for the term [triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_(mathematics)), but that generally implies arbitrary members whereas your application seems quite specific, so you should rather go with `TypedPair` or something

Comment: @Bergi I like `TypedPair`. Or perhaps `TypedKeyValuePair`.

Comment: The issue with having `Pair` as part of the name is that it is a misnomer for any struct with more than two properties, although I agree that these names are a good attempt (and naming things is hard) -- but then I guess `TypedKeyValueTriple` or using a Tuple generic that takes a number could also be a good method `KeyValueType & Tuple<3>`

Comment: @GrayedFox I don't know your application, but it looks like `type` is a meta property whereas only `key` and `value` are holding the actual data, so "Pair" would still be appropriate. I would avoid "Tuple" and "Triple" and use something more application-specific, unless you really have composite type without any semantics (other than knowing how many members it has). Given your property names are not just meaningless `first`, `second` and `third`, there seems to be a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3-tuple or triple are commonly used in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3)

> The Tuple<T1,T2,T3> class represents a 3-tuple, or triple, which is a tuple that has three components.

and [in IEEE](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22triple%22+%223-tuple%22+site%3Aieee.org), such as in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9103014)

> The triple N = (P, T , F) is a net

> A labeled PN is a 3-tuple GL = (N, 6, L)

Comment: Epic. I dig the terms `triple` and `3-tuple` here as it is much more specific than the arbitrary `Tuple` term that can hold many properties. Thanks